# uninstall genexus evolution 3 from windows 7 shows error after reinstall

Tags: windows-7, genexus

I just uninstalled genexus evolution 3 Trial on windows 7 because I thought it was the cause of a problem. Now, I want to install it again but the installer gives me the error code 2343. Take in mind that this is the trial version. When I click on the option "uninstall" that comes from the installer, it just freezes up and does not respond. Any solution on how to fully uninstall or what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem it was already reported and it will be uploaded the new setup with the release of X Evolution 3 Upgrade 2.

Meanwhile this is the work arround to fix it,
Download this tool:  http://support2.microsoft.com/fixit/

And follow this steps:

1- Choose select the problem and apply the fix for mi

2- Choose Uninstalling

3- Choose GeneXus X Evolution 3 Trial from the list

4- Select Try Uninstalling

This should fix your problem, then you can install the new version of  GeneXus X Evolution 3 Trial